# What is the significance of the intro to The Rings of Power?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-rings-of-power

The intro to *The Lord of the Rings: The Rings of Power* shows small stones or sand forming various shapes and patterns.

Other than looking cool, **do these shapes and patterns, and the sand, have any significance or symbolism?**

One of the patterns seems to be the titular Rings of Power, showing the One Ring surrounded by eight other Rings of Power. Does this pattern have any significance? Are these eight, any of the particular Rings of Power?

[image: screencap of pattern described above]

Some of the shapes and patterns formed by the sand:
[image: screencap of shapes and patterns shown in the intro][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: https://screenrant.com/lotr-rings-of-power-opening-credits-explained/ - The various symbols represent the rings, Ainar, Gondor, etc.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/LOTR_on_Prime/comments/x43gp9/comment/imupji8/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3 - The animation itself is done with mock 'cymatics' (using sound waves to rearrange sand on a tray) which apparently represents middle-Earth being 'sung' into existence

Comment: @Valorum I guessed that sound waves were being employed but missed the connection with Arda being sung into existence. That is so cool.

Comment: I assumed the final circle was Numenor sinking into a chasm

Comment: @ibid - That's the Amazon cash sinking into the pocket of the Tolkien family

Comment: As Valorum said, the visuals of the intro are intended to represent the [Ainulindalë](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ainulindal%C3%AB). The dark 'river' of sand is the discord of Melkor entering the music, which happens at the same time as the segment with fragments of Black Speech.